# Dynamically create a database connection for SQL Server

Tags: c#

Is there a way of inputting username, password & data source name from user instead of hardcoding them?

Right now I have hardcoded in app.config like this

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SQLConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=db01\instance01;Initial Catalog=testdb; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=testuser;Password=readonly; Connection Timeout=60;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

When I run the console app, I want it to print how to enter the parameters and then accept parameters.
How can I do this?

Thanks
Rashmi

Comment: You should look into string.Format() function, at least.  What have you tried, btw?

Comment: Use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set the connection string as first parameter.

```
string username = Console.ReadLine();

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("User ID=" + username);
```

Additionally you can take a look at the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that does more for the work for you.

Comment: sorry, got pulled into another project. Haven't had the time to work on this. Will definitely post my results.

Comment: got it to work. Console.WriteLine("Enter DataSource");
stringBuilder.DataSource = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter userid"); & so on
Console.WriteLine("Generated Connection String = " + stringBuilder.ConnectionString);
How can I show "**" when user types in password?

Comment: You can't. You can hide input from the user though. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx